# return pdo result from outisde anonymous function inside class

Tags: php, function, pdo, return

I've created an anonymous function to get some sql results so i don't have to write it everytime :

```
function select($sql){
    global $connexion; // config connection 
    $query = $connexion->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    return $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
}
```

I've created a class to get the meta information from my DB :

```
class PageInfo {
    public function get_meta($page_name){
            $sql = "SELECT description, keywords FROM pages WHERE titre='$page_name'";
            select($sql); //call the first function
            global $query;
            while( $results = $query->fetch() ){
                echo "test";
            }
    }
}
```

Then i call the class like that:

```
$PageInfo = new PageInfo();  
$PageInfo->get_meta('homepage');
```

Don't understant why i get this fatal error :

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object
```

Thanks for your precious help

Comment: This makes my eyes hurt. If you are going to use global everywhere, you might as well just access your database via static functions or a singleton. At least that will be readable

Answer (score 2):

You never did `global $query` inside your `select()` function. That means `$query` in there is a local variable, and your DB results will get trashed/destroyed once the function returns.

Plus, using global variables is just plain horrible. Especially for this. You're limiting yourself to a **SINGLE** query in-flight at any given time. Why not return the actual result instead?

```
function query($sql) {
    $result = $connextion->execute($sql);
    return $result;
}

$results = query($sql);
while($row = $results->fetch()) {
    ...
}
```